# [modified]How to find the last value in a column meeting a condition in R?

Tags: r

Following is example data:

```
> dput(sdf[,c(1,2)])
structure(list(vid = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), svelo = c(15, 16, 
17, 16, 13, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 10, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
)), .Names = c("vid", "svelo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

`vid` is vehicle ID & `svelo` is speed. My main goal is to identify 2 rows in `svelo` column which meet some conditions, as below, and create a new column `xf`:

if `svelo`==0 & and it is the last value in the column (as in row number 13 in example data) then `xf` = `l`.
Also, the first value in `svelo` after the `l` (as in row number 14 in example data) should be labelled as `f` in `xf`. Following is what I have tried:

```
sdf <- ddply(sdf, 'vid', transform, xf=c(NA,ifelse(diff(svelo)!=0, 'f','no')))
```

But this clearly fails to meet the goals. Here is what output should look like:

```
> dput(sdf)
structure(list(vid = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), svelo = c(15, 16, 
17, 16, 13, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 10, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), xf = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", "l", "f", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".")), .Names = c("vid", 
"svelo", "xf"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

## EDIT

Following is the original data frame `data12`. The `vid` and `svelo`in this case are column 2 `Vehicle.ID` and column 21 `svel`:

```
> dput(head(data12,3))
structure(list(X = 121:123, Vehicle.ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Frame.ID = 133:135, 
    Total.Frames = c(437L, 437L, 437L), Global.Time = c(1118846992200, 
    1118846992300, 1118846992400), Local.X = c(17.352, 17.479, 
    17.606), Local.Y = c(527.124, 530.629, 534.131), Global.X = c(6451487.556, 
    6451490.079, 6451492.601), Global.Y = c(1872997.295, 1872994.868, 
    1872992.442), Vehicle.Length = c(14.5, 14.5, 14.5), Vehicle.width = c(4.9, 
    4.9, 4.9), Vehicle.class = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Vehicle.velocity = c(34.91, 
    34.99, 34.99), Vehicle.acceleration = c(1.18, 0.09, -0.23
    ), Lane = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Preceding.Vehicle.ID = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Following.Vehicle.ID = c(13L, 13L, 13L), Spacing = c(0, 
    0, 0), Headway = c(0, 0, 0), Time = c(13.3, 13.4, 13.5), 
    svel = c(37.29, 37.11, 36.96), sacc = c(0.07, 0.11, 0.15), 
    PrecVehClass = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
    FollVehClass = c(2L, 2L, 2L), spgps = structure(c(9L, 9L, 
    9L), .Label = c("[0,4.5]", "(4.5,9]", "(9,13.5]", "(13.5,18]", 
    "(18,22.5]", "(22.5,27]", "(27,31.5]", "(31.5,36]", "(36,40.5]", 
    "(40.5,45]", "(45,49.5]", "(49.5,54]", "(54,58.5]", "(58.5,63]", 
    "(63,67.5]", "(67.5,72]", "(72,76.5]", "(76.5,76.8]"), class = "factor"), 
    PrecVehVel = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PrecVehAcc = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), lane.change = structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c(".", "yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
"Vehicle.ID", "Frame.ID", "Total.Frames", "Global.Time", "Local.X", 
"Local.Y", "Global.X", "Global.Y", "Vehicle.Length", "Vehicle.width", 
"Vehicle.class", "Vehicle.velocity", "Vehicle.acceleration", 
"Lane", "Preceding.Vehicle.ID", "Following.Vehicle.ID", "Spacing", 
"Headway", "Time", "svel", "sacc", "PrecVehClass", "FollVehClass", 
"spgps", "PrecVehVel", "PrecVehAcc", "lane.change"), row.names = 7750:7752, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to modify the code you provided for this data frame but got following error:

```
    data12["xf"] <- "."                              #create a new column xf
for(i in unique(data12$Vehicle.ID)){                               #loop through all vid's
  if(sum(data12[,2][data12[,2]==i])>0){             #check if the particular vid is existing in data
    current_vid <- which(data12[,2]==i)          #get all rows with the current vid-number
    first_vid_element <- min(current_vid)     #get the first row of the current vid-number
    last_vid_element <- max(current_vid)      #get the last row of the current vid-number
    #the following two lines are similar to my first answer but restricted to the rows that are relevant for the current vid-number
    data12[max(which(data12[,21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element]==0))+first_vid_element-1,29] <- "l"
    data12[max(which(data12[,21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element]==0))+first_vid_element,29] <- "f" 
  }
}



Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, max(which(data12[, 21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element] ==  : 
      non-existent rows not allowed
    In addition: Warning message:
    In max(which(data12[, 21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element] ==  :
      no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Is any `plyr` solution possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: you are getting the error because in your example, there is no row where svel == 0 (therefore r says "non-existing rows are not allowed").
if you check, whether the particular vid contains at least one row where svel ==0, this solution works:

```
data12["xf"] <- "."                              #create a new column xf
for(i in 1:10){                               #loop through all vid's
  if(sum(data12$Vehicle.ID[data12$Vehicle.ID==i])){       #check if the particular vid is existing in data
  current_vid <- which(data12$Vehicle.ID==i)       #get all rows with the current vid-number
  first_vid_element <- min(current_vid)     #get the first row of the current vid-number
  last_vid_element <- max(current_vid)      #get the last row of the current vid-number
  #check if the minimum svel value for that vid is 0 (if not, you get the error that non-existent rows are not allowed)
  if(min(data12$svel[first_vid_element:last_vid_element]) == 0){
  #the following two lines are similar to my first answer but restricted to the rows that are relevant for the current vid-number
    data12[max(which(data12[,21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element]==0))+first_vid_element-1,29] <- "l"
    data12[max(which(data12[,21][first_vid_element:last_vid_element]==0))+first_vid_element,29] <- "f"  
   }
 }
}
```

note that i assume in this solution that svel cannot be negative

Comment: @umairdurrani i cant comment on your edited question directly, so i comment here: you havent adapted the code correctly, the `for(i in...)` loop has to loop through the range of values in vid. for this you could try using `for(i in unique(data12$Vehicle.ID))` and you havent replaced all `sdf` entries with your new dataframe `data12` - if you change all `sdf` entries i think it should work. I dont know a `plyr` solution unfortunately

Comment: I've corrected the code but error is exactly the same.

Comment: @umairdurrani see my updated answer and let me know if it works for you. make sure to have some 0 in the svel-column (otherwise the function will not do anything)

Answer (score 1):

```
sdf["xf"] <- "."
sdf[max(which(sdf[,2]==0)),3] <- "l"
sdf[max(which(sdf[,2]==0))+1,3] <- "f"
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answers.

Comment: the first line adds a column named xf. inside the which() function i identify all rows that satisfy svelo==0 and by using max(which()) i get the last row of them and insert "l". in the third line, i simply use the same row +1 and insert "f"

Comment: @beginneR In my original data frame there are several unique vehicle IDs (vid) with many zeros in svelo column. How can I apply the same commands AFTER splitting the data frame by vehicle ID first. I am not sure how to use the above code to create a function. You can see that I was trying to achieve the same in the example code in my question

Comment: @umairdurrani i have added another answer. if that is not what you wanted to do, please explain your problem in more detail